# How to reference Cosmos table API from within azure function?

Tags: c#, azure, csx

I'm trying to compile a project I've written in C# script, in the azure portal(can't get any other environment to work).

I'm trying to reference the cosmos table API within my function:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"
#r "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs"
#r "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions"
#r "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage"
#r "Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table"

using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Bindings.Runtime;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table;
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
[Error] run.csx(6,1): error CS0006: Metadata file 'Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table' could not be found
2019-09-26T13:50:37.115 [Error] run.csx(14,23): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Cosmos' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Azure' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

How can I make azure function find the reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This namespace is not included in Azure function. You need to add the dll file to Azure function app by yourself. Refer to [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/04/13/how-to-add-assembly-references-to-an-azure-function-app/) for the detailed steps.